# PAYDAY 2 "This is a butcher mod pack item" bug?

Tags: payday-2

I just bought the $40 dlc thing in the store which includes all the extras for the game and when I go to the OVE9000 Saw it still says 'NOT AVAILABLE'. I don't know what the problem with this is because I already purchased the pack and it's still not available.

Comment: The attachments for the saw and this is on Xbox one if that matters

Comment: After you bought it, make sure it's actually installed.  Go to your My games and apps section, find Payday, and manage the game.  Make sure all the items are installed.

Comment: Have you skilled up the [relevant skill](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Portable_Saw)? I believe by default it's unlocked for _Primary Weapon_ but you need the skill to use it for the _Secondary Weapon_

Answer (score 3):

The mods for the OVE9000 saw are non-achievement mods. This means you have to recieve them from a card drop at the end of a heist or a crime spree, or as a reward from a side mission.

By purchasing the butchers dlc you are now able to recieve these mods as drops, now you only have to get them from those drops.